Angular - [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
why i am getting this avertissement message [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking  événements. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. it was after adding this api
getDate(): void {
    const { datesFromAPI, formatterDate } = this;
    const latestDateFromAPI = datesFromAPI.length === 0 ? formatterDate(this.creditReportFix.datereportfix) : datesFromAPI[datesFromAPI.length - 1];
    
    if (!this.data.find(item => formatterDate(item.date_reporting) === latestDateFromAPI)) {
        this.servicesRepo.getDataPortefeuilleDirect(latestDateFromAPI).subscribe(data2 => {
            this.data.push(...data2);
        });
    }
}

i tried to modify my getDate but it doesn't work

I can't see any reference to an event handler in the code you posted? Or am I missing something?
